# controller create function: @user.save not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i have a view which asks users for their email (just the email, no password). So i made a Emailuser model for that purpose as below:

```
class Emailuser < ActiveRecord::Base
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
    validates :email, presence:   true,
  format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

and the respective "Emailusers_controller" as below:

```
class EmailusersController < ApplicationController

    def home
      @user = Emailuser.new
    end

    def show
      @user = Emailuser.find(params[:id])        
    end

    def create
      @user = Emailuser.new(params[:user])
       if @user.save  # -----------------------> not working
         render 'show'
       else
         render 'public'
      end
    end

    def public

    end
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">


      <p>Email ID: <%= @user.email %></p>

  </aside>


</div>
```

home.html.erb:

```
 <%=form_for(@user) do |f|%>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
<div id="example1">
<section>



      <%= f.label :email %>     
      <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Enter Email"%>
 <%= f.submit "Create my account" %>

</section>
</div>
<%end%>
```

its just when i run the above code it renders the else part always that means the email is not being saved. 
I dont know why is it not working. Please help.

Comment: are you using proper email address because you have put validation for email.just try save! and see if any error shows in log

Comment: undefined local variable or method `save' for #<EmailusersController:0x38c1e88>

Comment: post your parameter log

Comment: It's quite impossible you get this error with this code. Are you sure you posted current code?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@user = Emailuser.new(params[:emailuser])`

Comment: @rsb why you deleted your answer i think that was right here he is directly passing params to create action  which is worng

Comment: @Mayank although the suggestion to use strong params was right, it didn't solve OP's problem.

Comment: I am not getting any error, its just when i run the above code it renders the else part always that means the email is not being saved.

Comment: It seems your validation fails every time. You should debug it with `@user.errors.full_messages`.

Comment: ["Email can't be blank", "Email is invalid"] it gives me this error. even when i use VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[a-z]+\Z/i

Comment: @MarekLipka look at the above comment. I know i am missing something very simple.

Comment: So you have your answer. You should rebuild your email validation regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this.
Actually adding strong parameters has done the trick.
I got it working by adding the following:

```
private

    def user_params
      params.require(:emailuser).permit(:email)
    end
```

Thanks all anyways.

Comment: everything else was fine

Answer (score 0):

The first place to start will be to use [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for your class declarations & [snake case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for your file names:

```
Class EmailUser < ActiveRecord::Base #-> app/models/email_user.rb

Class EmailUserController < ApplicationController # -> app/controllers/email_users_controller.rb
```

The other problem you may have will be with your validation - if you update your class declarations, please let us know the logs for the request

Comment: You're right with your first suggestion. But it doesn't really solve OP's problem (look at the comments below the question) and doesn't address other, more serious problems with this code.

Comment: Thanks Marek - you are right. I felt it was required to get his code right - after that, we need RSB's answer and potentially something with his validations

Comment: RSB's answer has the same problem as yours. The question itself is written very badly and in this form it should be closed, in my opinion.

Comment: @MarekLipka whats wrong with the question? is ther something else i should provide?

Comment: @MarekLipka I am not getting any error, its just when i run the above code it renders the else part always that means the email is not being saved.